# explicit wait on selenium on python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a webpage where I need to expand the items list by clicking expand button several times.

So as I researched how to do this in smart way, I've been trying to use explicit wait with expected condition (`element_to_be_clickable`).

here is my test code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

btn_xpath = '//*[@id="contents"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/dongpark/Downloads/chromedriver')  # calling chrome driver from local folder
browser.get('http://cu.bgfretail.com/event/plus.do?category=event&depth2=1&sf=N')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
time.sleep(8)


def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):

    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


while True:

    button = check_exists_by_xpath(btn_xpath)

    if button is False:
        print "done"
        break
    else:
        print "more"
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, btn_xpath)))
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath).click()
```

`check_exists_by_xpath` just tests if the expand button is still available on the page.

When I run this, I get:

```
File "/Users/dongpark/Documents/kuk/firstSelenium/test.py", line 37, in <module>      browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath).click()
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (418, 920). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ico"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

If I just give enough sleep before the click it works but I wanna make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `check_exists_by_xpath` to wait for element presence:

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):

  try:
      wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
  except NoSuchElementException:
      return False
return True
```